# declaring a global function across all views

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have a function for eg. that I with to have across all views in my app.
How would I go about defining that. Where should the function be written.

read somewhere here that one possible solution is to define the function as a UIViewController extension like so:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func displayAlert(title:String, error:String, buttonText: String) {
    ...
   }
}
```

where should such a procedure be declared?

Thanks

Comment: You want to access it across all views or all view controllers? There's a difference.

Comment: please explain difference

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Swift file and name it something like:
`UIViewController+DisplayAlert.swift`

In there is where you can add the code in your question.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func displayAlert(title:String, error:String, buttonText: String) {
    ...
   }
}
```

Since it is extending UIViewController, you'll be able to access this function on all subclasses of UIViewController.

Comment: do i need to import file?

Comment: @JohnyDGood Nope. There's nothing to import. It's now treated like its part of UIKit.